# Probability for Minimum of Random Permutation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations, random-variables, conditional-probability

Consider a random permutation $\pi$ of the set $\lbrace 1, \cdots, n\rbrace$ and consider the event $E_i := \lbrace \pi : \pi_i = \min\left(\pi_1, \cdots, \pi_i\right) \rbrace$ and the indicator random variable $X_i(\pi) = \mathbb{1}[\pi \in E_i]$ for this event. It is intuitive that $P[E_i] = \frac{1}{i}$ because if we just look at the first $i$ numbers of the permutation sequence, the chance that any number is the minimum is $1/i$.

What I want to try and show is that $X_i$ is independent from $X_{i-1}$. This seems intuitively the case since knowing $\pi_{i-1}$ is the minimum of its previous subsequence does not necessarily mean $\pi_{i}$ will or will not be the minimum of its corresponding subsequence. However, I am not sure how to rigorously show this? Clearly the intersection of $E_i \bigcap E_{i-1} \neq \emptyset$, so the question is does $P[E_i \bigcap E_{i-1}] = P[E_i] P[E_{i-1}] = \frac{1}{i (i-1)}$. Alternatively, how can we show that $P[E_i | E_{i-1}] = P[E_i]$? Any tips are welcome.

A more general version of this I am looking into is showing that for sime fixed $k$, $P[X_i = x | X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \cdots, X_{i_k}] = P[X_i = x]$ for distinct $i_j \in \lbrace 1, \cdots, n\rbrace$. I am not really sure how to go about showing either of these, but clearly this more general version of independence leads to the simpler one stated above.

Perhaps some tips on the simpler problem will help me see how to tackle this latter one.

Comment: So, $E_1$ means that $\pi _1=1,$ there are $(n-1)!$ permutations so $P(E_1)=1/n.$ Am i missing sometjing?

Comment: @Phicar: $E_1$ is the set of permutations such that $\pi_1 = \min (\pi_1) = \pi_1$, which means $E_1$ is all permutations feasible since $\pi_1 = \pi_1$ is always true for every permutation, thus $P[E_1] = 1$. Does that help clarify any confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the intersection event if $\pi \in E_i\cap E_{i-1}$ we know that  $\min \{\pi _1,\cdots,\pi _i\}=\min \{\min \{\pi_1,\cdots ,\pi _{i-1}\},\pi _i\}=\min \{\pi _{i-1},\pi _i\}=\pi _i,$ hence
$$P(E_i\cap E_{i-1})=P(\pi _i<\pi _{i-1}<\min \{\pi _1,\cdots ,\pi _{i-2}\})=\frac{\binom{n}{i}(i-2)!(n-i)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{i(i-1)},$$ because you choose $i$ of them from the $n$, you shuffle $i-2$(the order of the first $i-2$ does not matter) and you shuffle the remaining $n-i$ elements.
**For your question:**
$$P(E_2\cap E_7)=P(\pi _7<\pi _2<\pi _1)=\frac{\binom{n}{7}(n-7)!|\{\sigma \in S_6:\sigma _2<\sigma _1\}|}{n!}=\frac{\binom{n}{7}(n-7)!\frac{6!}{2}}{n!}=\frac{1}{7*2}$$

Comment: Wow, awesome. I'm going to need to think about what you did here, though the high level comments make sense. I see I will need to brush up on my combinatorics. For the latter case, it seems you would do something similar such as $\min\lbrace \pi_{i_1}, \cdots, \pi_{i_k} \rbrace = \pi_{i_k}$, assuming I order them like $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k$. Then we would find $P(\pi_{i_k} < \cdots < \pi_{i_1} < \min\lbrace \pi_1, \cdots, \pi_{i_1 - 1}\rbrace)$, which (in my head) should share a resemblance with what you wrote, though a little trickier.

Comment: It seems the more general case is not as simple as I put it. I can kind of see a result that gives the correct answer, but the combinatorics behind it is iffy. Suppose we wish to just find $P(E_2 \cap E_7)$ for some $n > 7$. Under the assumption of independence that the desired result shows, $P(E_2 \cap E_7) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{7}$. To get this, taking into account the variability of $\pi_3, \pi_4, \cdots, \pi_6$ seem to be the tough point. Any thoughts?

Comment: I edited the question to show you how to think about it. You should think about it sequentially from the biggest index to the smallest. When you remove the biggest index it becomes a subproblem (So i guess induction should help here).

Comment: So it looks like $S_6$ represents sequences of length 6, correct? Given so, I think I see how you arrive at your $6!/2$ result and I think I see how to get there for more set intersections (for the more general case). That said, is there any reference book or online notes that you could recommend to help me improve my background in these combinatorics like this?

Comment: Yes, is the symmetric group on $6$ elements. I can recommend you Martin Aigner "A course in enumeration" (it has everything one has to know about counting). Or a more elementary book: Miklos Bona "A walk throught combinatorics".

Comment: Thank you for the insights! I just downloaded the first book you mentioned, so I will check that out first. Thank you very much for your help!